# What is $(3n+3)!$ equal to

Tags: factorial

Is $(3n+3)!$ equal to:

a) $(3n+3)\cdot(3n)\cdot(3n-3)\cdot(3n-6)\cdot...\cdot(1)$

b) $(3n+3)\cdot(3n+2)\cdot(3n+1)\cdot(3n)\cdot...\dot(1)$

I was wondering, since $$(n+1)!=(n+1)\cdot n!$$ Shouldn't the right option be a)? Because,

$$(3n+3)!$$

using the definition of the factorial equal to

$$(3n+3)!=(3n+3)\cdot(3(n-1)+3)!=(3n+3)\cdot(3n)!$$

Comment: I think you've confused yourself by using $n$ to refer to two different variables, one being the argument of the factorial and one being the argument of $f(n) = (3n+3)!.$

Comment: It's easy enough to try a small value of $n$ (e.g. $n = 1$) to see that a) doesn't work. In fact, if you do, you'll realise that a) is not even well-formed! Note that $3n + 3$, $3n$, $3n - 3$, etc are all multiples of $3$. When does the factor of $1$ appear?

Comment: Note that:

$$(3n+3)! = (3n+3) \cdot (3n + 2) \cdot (3n + 1) \cdot\underbrace{3n \cdot (3n - 1) \cdot (3n - 2) \dots \cdot 2 \cdot 1}_{=(3n)!},$$

which means $$(3n+3)! = (3n+3) \cdot (3n+2) \cdot (3n+1)\cdot (3n)!$$
In general 
$$(K+3)!= (K+3) \cdot (K+2) \cdot (K+1)\cdot (K)!$$
for an integer $K=3n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factorial function receives $Q$ and returns $Q(Q-1)(Q-2)\dots 2\cdot 1$.  This is $(3n+3)(3n+3-1)(3n+3-2)\dots 2\cdot 1$ for $3n+3=Q$.

Note that variables such as $n,x,y$ etc. are used repeatedly in various contexts but without keeping the same values in between.  The point of using $n$ over and over again is often to signal that it refers to an integer (but usually not the same integer from one context to another).